# How can I call git's built-in diff command directly after configuring a different visual "git diff" substitute?

Tags: git, alias, diff

I have configured `git diff` to be a command that calls substitute diff for viewing file differences i.e `/usr/bin/vim -dR "$2" "$3"` and that doesn't work when I want to create a patch using `git diff > patchfile`.

Is there a way to invoke directly git's own built in diff without disabling the subsitute diff I use for visual compares?

Comment: If you want a patch, there's [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch). No need to misuse `git diff`.

Comment: `--no-ext-diff`

Comment: @Guildenstern Who would have thought? Will you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff --no-ext-diff
```

In general look for a `--no-thing` option for turning whatever `--thing` off. git(1) has a lot of those. Good for conveniently turning off defaults. Sometimes they’re documented together as `--[no-]thing` and sometimes separately in the man pages.